# Why will this XPath work in PowerShell but not Task Scheduler?

Tags: powershell, xpath, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer

I'm writing an event that fires when a specific USB key is unplugged from the machine to lock it. I can run the following fine from within PowerShell with Get-WinEvent and I get the results I expect back.

```
*[System[(EventID=2102)]] and *[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[@instance="SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR`#DISK&VEN_&PROD_&REV_PMAP#070732AAB9D7B007&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}"]]]
```

However, plugging that into the Edit Event Filter query results in 'The Event Log query specified is invalid.'  What gives? The entire filter is such:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational">
*[System[(EventID=2102)]] and *[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[@instance="SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_&PROD_&REV_PMAP#070732AAB9D7B007&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}"]]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML `QueryList` is not well formed because of the raw `&` characters.

Try `&amp;` there instead for each of the four occurrences of `&`.

Comment: I don't know why PowerShell didn't complain about that. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not for XPath but for XML itself that `&` must be escaped.  If you specified the XPath to PowerShell or any other library as a string rather than embedded in an XML file, you would be able to use a raw `&` without problem.